# Who is the yellow-haired character in opening of Midnight Occult Civil Servants?

Tags: midnight-occult-civil-servants

I recently watched the series *Midnight Occult Civil Servants* (Mayonaka no Okaruto) on Crunchyroll.  The opening includes several seconds of a yellow-haired character who did not appear in the anime.

[image: from opening of Midnight Occult Civil Servants]

You can see sort of a ribbon of sand floating at his eye line.  The main character, a reincarnated high spiritual power human with red hair, has a gift to understand and speak in Yokai languages, called Ears of Sand.  My guess is the yellow- and red-haired guys are somehow related.  My guess is that the yellow-haired dude is from further in the manga than the anime goes.  Who is he?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't watched the anime but taking a look at the art from the manga volume covers, to me it looks like an artistic preference in the color used in the opening scene rather than a new character.

Here's a comparison of the anime and the manga covers:

[image]

[image]

This is especially noticeable in **Volume 3**'s cover. There's no green-haired character yet the cover art and the opening sequence also features the characters with green hairs and an overall color of green (not sure what term this is called in art). This leads to me to conclude that the opening scene you see was probably trying to copy the volume's majority of one color in the art in the scenes it portrays.

That said, I think that's the red-haired guy, Miyako Arata, if I'm correct.

Comment: I guess it probably is Arata.  I'm very used to hair color being used to help distinguish characters in an anime, so giving him different hair color for part of the opening confused me.